# PhoneGap - Socket IO

Tags: android, ios, sockets, cordova, socket.io

Im working on a PhoneGap application with Socket IO intregration.

```
DoTCP: function(driverid) {

  console.log("=== Opening up TCP ===");

  var Connections = 0;

  console.log("=== Cleaning between " + OpenConnections.length + "sockets that are disconnected ===");
  for (var i = 0; i < OpenConnections.length; i++) {
    if (OpenConnections[i] == null) {
      OpenConnections[i] = null;
    }
  };

  console.log("=== " + OpenConnections.length + " sockets up ===");

  if (OpenConnections.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < OpenConnections.length; i++) {
      if (OpenConnections[i].connected == true) {
        Connections++;
      }
    };
  }

  console.log("=== " + Connections + " socekts are connected ===");

  if (Connections == 0) {
    console.log("=== Creating a new socket ===");
    socket = io.connect('http://dispatch.pizza24.com:3000');
  }


  /**
   * Sends geo positions to the server every 60 seconds
   * @type {[type]}
   */
  if (TCPGeoPosInterval === false) {
    TCPGeoPosInterval = setInterval(function() {
      //if (socket.connected == true && GeoIntialized == true) {
      console.log("Sending postion... " + "P:" + Geo.Lat + ":" + Geo.Lon);
      socket.emit("data", "P:" + Geo.Lat + ":" + Geo.Lon);
      //}
    }, 60000);
  }


  /**
   * Send keep alive to the dispatch server
   * @type {[type]}
   */
  if (TCPInterval === false) {
    TCPInterval = setInterval(function() {
      //if (socket.connected == true) {
      console.log("Sending ping..." + "I:" + UserData.DriverID);
      socket.emit('data', "I:" + UserData.DriverID);
      //}
    }, 60000);
  }


  socket.on('connect', function() {

    OpenConnections.push(socket);

    console.log("=== Socket connection has been established ===");
    console.log("=== Sending data I:" + UserData.DriverID + " to verify for socket server ===");
    socket.emit('data', "I:" + UserData.DriverID);

    /**
     * Connection is open - light up the icon
     */
    $(".server-status img").attr({
      "src": "img/dot-circle-o_on.png"
    });


    socket.on('anything', function(data, callback) {
      console.log("========" + data + "========");
    });

    socket.on('reconnect', function() {

      OpenConnections.push(socket);

      console.log("=== Socket reconnection has been established ===");
      console.log("=== Sending data I:" + UserData.DriverID + " to verify for socket server ===");
      socket.emit('data', "I:" + UserData.DriverID);

      /**
       * Connection is open - light up the icon
       */
      $(".server-status img").attr({
        "src": "img/dot-circle-o_on.png"
      });

    });



    socket.on('data', function(text) {

      if (text == "B:1") {
        console.log("=== Incoming dispatch, checking for orders ===");
        P24.DoCheck(UserData.DriverID, UserData.Token, Geo.Lat, Geo.Lon);
      }

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log("=== Socket has been disconnected ===");
      var Conn = 0;
      socket = null;

      console.log("=== Cleaning between " + OpenConnections.length + " sockets that are disconnected ===");
      for (var i = 0; i < OpenConnections.length; i++) {
        if (OpenConnections[i] != null || OpenConnections[i].connected == true) {
          Conn++;
        }
      };

      console.log("=== " + OpenConnections.length + " sockets up ===");

      if (Conn === 0) {

        console.log("=== No socket connections, setting upp the TCPConnTimeout ===");

        if (TCPConnTries >= 6) {
          TCPConnTries = 0;
          P24.AlertBox(Locale.Texts.alerttitle, Locale.Texts.tcp_connection_timeout);
        } else {
          TCPConnTries++;
        }


        $(".server-status img").attr({
          "src": "img/dot-circle-o_off.png"
        });

        console.log("######  Lost connection to TCP server  #######");

        clearInterval(TCPGeoPosInterval);
        clearInterval(TCPInterval);

        TCPGeoPosInterval = false;
        TCPInterval = false;

        TCPConnTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

          P24.DoTCP(UserData.DriverID);

        }, 30000);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

What happens is that I manage to establish a connection with the socket server and send the first data `I:DriverID`. But then after a minute when I should ping once again it disconnects and then tries to connect once again, but without sending `I:DriverID`. The `I:DriverID` needs to be sent for the server to accept the connection, if that particular data has not been sent the server will timeout the connection.

For some reason this error only occurs on android devices, it works at glance on the iOS device.